# Issues gaining access to sqlplus

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I recently installed oracle 11g enterprise manager version

first of all, the orcl would not work when I lunched it on internet explorer
`<error:cannot find page>`
I checked the status of dbconsole from SERVICE folder..(Started)

was able to gain access to sqlplus with my log in details

after a few weeks I couldn't gain access anymore with the same login details

I tried the following codes but still could not gain access

```
sqlplus/nolog
sql>connect / as sysdba
sql>desc dba_users
sql>select username,password from dba_users;
sql>desc dba_users(error: object dba_users does not exist)
sql>select username,password from dba_users;(error: database not open)
ALTER DATABASE OPEN READ ONLY;( error: database not mounted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to startup the database.

e.g.

```
. oraenv
SID
sqlplus / as sysdba
startup
```